# When starving, should you run or sprint in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

If hunger is an important factor, let's say you don't have any food and are far from your home, what's the best approach?

Walking, sprinting or sprinting and jumping?

Comment: If the player is truly starving, i.e. the hunger bar is depleted, sprinting is not an option.

Comment: Hunting for food. It's not all that rare. Even several pieces of rotten flesh eaten at once will help. If you have some wood in the Nether you can craft a bowl and make mushroom stew. There's Chorus Fruit in the End. Fish in the ocean, abundance of animals in normal biomes. It's unwise to proceed without your food situation solved, no matter what means of transport you take.

Comment: I think that sprinting is running so...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely walking. It doesn't increase hunger rate, whereas sprinting and jumping do. You can get a list of the hunger costs here: https://minecraft.wiki/w/Hunger#Exhaustion_level_increase

Comment: This is correct. The wiki says "...normal walking doesn't increase exhaustion, and therefore won't decrease saturation or the food bar." This would lead me to believe that the player can walk indefinitely as long as they are not jumping, sprinting, or doing anything else that increases exhaustion.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answers and comments you also will not be allowed to sprint once your hunger bar drops below a certain number.  You can go past halfway and still be able to sprint but once you hit about 4 hunger bars you cannot sprint anymore.

Answer (score -1):

What does consume more hunger?
Sprinting and jumping or just sprinting.
Technically a jump is 0.05 hunger depletion and sprinting 1block is 0.1.
But how does it count in a sprint+jump?
Which one is faster?